# how to use geocoding for googlemaps?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, promise

I am trying to get geocoding with googlemaps working. The problem I have is that the Geocoder in my code has not returned before centering the map again:

```
 GeoCoder.getLocations($scope.address).then(function(results) {
    var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
    $scope.center = {
      lat: latLng.k,
      lng: latLng.A
    };
    $scope.zoom = 10;
  });
```

In my gmaps directive I set the center of the map to the new lat/lng that are returned from the GeoCoder (see above). What is a better solution to call the service and when it has returned to set the new location? Maybe an async call?
This is the url plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/6Wg3UZNsJOHLQCmTJPCQ?p=preview

Comment: Your plunk is missing several javascript files. Hard to give an adequate answer without that.

Comment: try again should work now

Comment: I need to clarify something else for my answer. Are you asking how to defer the $scope.center assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just returning the center? Or chaining a promise for the center? You would resolve it when you are ready to center the map.

```
var centerPromise = GeoCoder.getLocations($scope.address).then(function(results) {
    var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
    $scope.nextCenter = {
        lat: latLng.k,
        lng: latLng.A
    };
    return new $q.defer().promise;
 });
```